# External XML to HTML

Tags: html, xml, external

I usually just build Wordpress websites. But because i know HTML and PHP basics I have been kindly asked to help out a friend with his idea.

**Idea (In Short)**

In the UK each vehicle has a registration number, this number is connected to a database called "DVLA". His idea is when you search a correct registration number, you will receive information on the vehicle relating to the registration number.

Access to the DVLA Database
He has been granted access to this database, with a username and password. I was hoping there would be some sample data that i just put on his web hosting and it would work (But no!). The only help, or snippet of code i get is this:

**HTTP GET**

The following is a sample HTTP GET request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```html
GET /capdvla_webservice/capdvla.asmx/DVLALookupVRM?SubscriberID=string&Password=string&vrm=string HTTP/1.1
Host: webservices.capnetwork.co.uk
```

```html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0"?>
xml
```

**HTTP POST**

The following is a sample HTTP POST request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```html
POST /capdvla_webservice/capdvla.asmx/DVLALookupVRM HTTP/1.1
Host: webservices.capnetwork.co.uk
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

SubscriberID=string&Password=string&vrm=string
```

```html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0"?>
xml
```

After i enter my ID and Password (To verify reg look-up), i enter the VRM - this is the registration number that we want to check the details of. The form gives me a XML document with all the vehicles data.

**The Big Question**

I have been searching none stop how to pull external XML from the DVLA an place the results to an online user who has entered their vehicle registration number, but i am getting know where, this is pretty much my last resort.

How do i get a user to enter there reg, link up with the DVLA database, and for the user to receive the information in bog standard HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a server-side scripting language to do it such as PHP. PHP has a SimpleXML library which can be used to read XML. I'm sure other server-side languages can do the job too. You will probably have to authenticate with the DVLA server before you can ask for any XML (they should have a guide on how to do that). You will have to write PHP for that as well as PHP to pull the XML. After the data is pulled you can format it however you want in HTML. Good luck.

Comment: I can currently pull data from the DVLA database, but it is in XML format. I was hoping i could just stylise the XML Data into something readable.

Thanks for the useful info and fast response!

Comment: No problem. You should be able to do this with and XML reading library. In PHP the xml would come out as an object. You could output it to a table or however you like.

Comment: Does it matter that the link is external? Will merging it into a website be do-able if the xml is on another domain? Thanks again!

Comment: It doesn't matter if the link is external. You can use file_get_contents in PHP and it will grab a web page externally or internally. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: I have used a few methods to try and include the XML page so i can add CSS to it an put it into a basic list. But whenever I call the page through any code - i get:

>Warning: >file_get_contents(http://webservices.capnetwork.co.uk/capdvla_webse>rvice/capdvla.asmx/DVLALookupVRM): failed to open stream: HTTP >request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in >/home/moretonc/public_html/test/vrm/vehicledata.php on line 2

When i submit the form on the user end, it goes straight to the DVLA XML on there server, instead of me pulling the data from it via PHP like you suggested. Thanks for help!

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://webservices.capnetwork.co.uk/capdvla_webservice/capdvla.asmx/DVLALookupVRM" in /home/moretonc/public_html/test/vrm/vehicledata.php on line 2

Comment: I was just trying to get you started. I am not sure why you are getting these errors. A 500 error means the web page you are trying to grab isn't showing for you though. Probably because I assume they want you to authenticate first. Basically if you can't type in the link and get to the page as a new user then you will have to read up on their API or if they allow you to grab data off their server. I would test the method/function on some random xml page on the internet first just to be sure.